# Service and Android Application lifecycle

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, android-service-binding

I'm a little bit confused. I've read that the biggest benefit of using a started service is that this is independent from the application so, even if the android kills your application, your service is still alive. My questions then are:

1) If my service works in the same process than the application, the service will be alive too?

2) I'm using a BroadcastReceiver to detect the changes in the device's connectivity so, if the application is killed but the service is not, would I still receive that connectivity changes?

3) If I want to get the current connectivity status from the service, could I do that by using the getApplicationContext() or it may returns null? In the second case, how could I get the current status of the network?

4) Similar to the connectivity, I'm sending an event through Otto's bus each time that the application changes its status from foreground to background (on application paused/resumed). So, my service is subscribed to that changes in order to know the current application status. If my application is killed, can I trust in that events? Or they could not be sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you use a foreground `Service`, it is not very likely to be abruptly killed. Having said that:

> If my service works in the same process than the application, the service will be alive too?

Well, no. Your `Service` is one component of your application. If it is alive, then so is the application (see also third question). *But* if you return `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from `onStartCommand()`, then it will be recreated if terminated by system (not if force-stopped) as soon as possible.

> I'm using a BroadcastReceiver to detect the changes in the device's connectivity so, if the application is killed but the service is not, would I still receive that connectivity changes?

For a static `BroadcastReceiver` (registered in the `Manifest`): that depends on how your application was terminated. If the user force-stopped it, then the receiver will only start working again after the user launched your application once more. In all other cases: a static receiver will be intact, and if the receiver was created and registered dynamically, then one should unregister it when shutting down the `Activity`/ `Service` in time to avoid memory leaks, so this kind of receivers is not meant to work 24/7 anyway.

> If I want to get the current connectivity status from the service, could I do that by using the getApplicationContext() or it may returns null?

That one is easier: `Service`, just like `Activity`, extends `ContextWrapper`. So if it is up and running, you can call `getApplicationContext()`.

> I'm sending an event through Otto's bus each time that the application changes its status from foreground to background (on application paused/resumed)... If my application is killed, can I trust in that events? Or they could not be sent?

I think here you may be mixing up `Application` and `Activity`. Because if the `Service` needs to be notified, then you're most likely thinking of a visible part of your application and something like the famous incoming telephone call.

In this case, your Activity can notify the `Service` either in `onPause()` or in `onStop()`. Both are guaranteed to be called since `Version HONEYCOMB`.

Now I  must confess I'm not sure about Otto's EventBus, but one option which would certainly work is having a `Service` with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` and notifying the Service by calling `startService(myNotifyingIntent)`.

Normally, your application process will not be killed instantly just because the current `Activity` is no longer in the foreground. So it is quite likely that the `Service` will get any notification you send from `onPause()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. One question, I have an activity which totally depends of a service result in order to set all its views. So, that would be a good practice to just inflate the views in the onCreate method of the activity and then, on the onServiceConnected method set up all the views of the activity? Would the user see an strange behaviour (or the service will be bound so fast that the user will never notice anything? Thanks again!

Comment: @FVod - One such use case for me was an audio player app with a home screen widget with play/pause etc. plus title/artist info and the same infos/ controls in the MainActivity. My Activity inflates the Views in onCreate() and then in onResume() starts the Service which has to gather all info about the current MediaPlayer state and send it (local broadcast) to the Activity. Only then it can update the View content. It *seems* to work nicely (compared to other apps) on a Samsung Galaxy S3mini (Jellybean), but of course nobody can tell for every device out there.

Answer (score 0):

1) Service dies by default. But you can override **onStartCommand** and return **START_STICKY**. There are another flags too. So read more about it 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

2) Yes, I would take changes from receiver.

3) getApplicationContext() shouldn't return NULL.

4) If your application had killed, onPause should have been called. So service knows that app in background. When you start the application, onResume calls, so service will know that app in foreground also.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) in Android. You can find more about [Service lifecycle here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle)